# Show data in swimlane/ngx-charts Angular 4

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

For the first time, i am using "swimlane/ngx-charts" and i want to show the data that i have generated when i run the code. In console i don't get any error, but i don't get "ngx-charts-pie-chart".

Code HTML:

```
<ngx-charts-pie-chart
         [view]="view"
         [scheme]="colorScheme"
         [results]="infoChartsFree"
         [explodeSlices]="explodeSlices"
         [labels]="showLabels"
         [doughnut]="doughnut"
         [gradient]="gradient">
       </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
```

Code status-parking.ts:

```
view: any[] = [700, 400];

  // options

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#ff0909','#048506','#000274','#ff5309','#00ff04','#0004ff']
  };

  // pie
  showLabels = true;
  explodeSlices = false;
  doughnut = false;

public getFree(idZone:number){
    let freeObs=this._iTipologiazona.getnumberFree(idZone);
    freeObs.subscribe(data=>{
      this.status=data;
      let tipo_veicolo:string;
      let c:number=0;
      for(var i=0; i<this.status.length;i++){
        tipo_veicolo=this.status[i].tipo.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+this.status[i].tipo.slice(1).toLowerCase();
        c=c+this.status[i].occupati;
        this.status[i].tipo=tipo_veicolo;
        var free="Posti "+tipo_veicolo + " liberi";
        var notFree="Posti "+tipo_veicolo + " occupati";
        this.infoChartsFree.push(new InfoCharts());
        this.infoChartsFree[i].name=free;
        this.infoChartsFree[i].value=this.status[i].totale-c;
        this.InfoChartsNotFree.push(new InfoCharts());
        this.InfoChartsNotFree[i].name=notFree;
        this.InfoChartsNotFree[i].value=c;

        this.infocharts.push(this.infoChartsFree[i]);
        this.infocharts.push(this.InfoChartsNotFree[i]);
      }

      this.jsonInfoCharts=JSON.stringify(this.infocharts)
      Object.assign(this.infoChartsFree)

      console.log(this.jsonInfoCharts);
      this.total_notfree=c;
      this.total_free=this.totale-this.total_notfree;

    })
  }
```

This is that i get in console:
https://ibb.co/hymKum

Comment: Where do you call your `getFree` method ?

Comment: @valakhosravi I call it in ngOnInit()

Comment: Try it in ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: I try to insert it in ngAfterViewInit(), and after in constructor(), but i get the same solution. I don't show any charts

Comment: Can you leave a demo for me in [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/iMHhbjI44zTr0mTTi6MU/)?

Comment: I have solved my problem using the fusion charts...Thanks @valakhosravi